# App crash ios after webview loading

Tags: ios

I'm using webview in my app..When I come back to the previous page,sometimes it works fine,but at times,the app crashing.Can anyone help how to solve this.

Comment: Can you put some details? Code, error messages

Comment: can u show the crash report

Comment: Does it says memory leaks somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[urwebpage dealloc];
}
```

This may be because you are navigating before the webview loads,so dealloc the memory when the webview stop loading.

Answer (score 0):

In your dealloc method, write following line.

```
-(void) dealloc
{
   [webView stopLoading];
}
```

Comment: I have tried stopLoading but no use :( @Apurv

Comment: what is there on your console when app gets crashed?

Comment: It showing unexcepted memory exception

Comment: Show the code which is creating the web view.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the loading of WebView in your viewWillDisappear method:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear{
    [self.WebView stopLoading]
     self.WebView.delegate = nil;
 }
```

This may help you.